# Are there 3d shapes such that their surface area is equal to the sum of the surface area of two similar sub-shapes?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Are there any 3d structures such that their surface area is equal to the sum of the surface area of two similar (smaller) non-intersecting copies of the original, contained within the original?
Does there exist: $S\subset \mathbb R^3$ with $A,B\subset S$  where $A\sim B\sim S$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ such that the sum of the surface area of $A$ and $B$ is equal to the surface area of $S$?

Additionally, I would be interested if there are higher dimensional shapes with similar contained shapes the measure of whose boundaries are equal to the measure of the boundary of the original.

Edit: $S$ has non-zero volume.

Comment: Take for example three concentric spherical shells, of radii $5,4,3$. They don't intersect, the two smaller spheres are contained in the big one, and $$S_5=4\pi5^2=4\pi4^2+4\pi 3^2=S_4+S_3$$

Comment: @Andrei I'm probably making a mistake, but wouldn't a sphere of radius 4 within a sphere of radius 5 leave a maximum gap of 2 units? So how would a sphere of radius 3 units fit within the sphere as well without intersection?

Comment: The example @Andrei gave is 3 _concentric_ spheres. So the 4-radius and 3-radius spheres are non intersecting, as you asked. But that's probably not what you intended. :-)

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Thanks, that was indeed not what I intended. I should have specified that $S$ must have a topological dimension of 3.

Comment: Two $1/\sqrt2\times\sqrt2\times1$ parallelepipeds can be contained into a $1\times2\times\sqrt2$ parallelepiped, but their intersection is not empty: it's a zero-volume surface.